# upload image using angularjs in api centric web applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I am new at developing API centric web applications with AngularJS. We are going to use AngularJS as frontend framework. We have a upload functionality in the application. I want to upload an image/document using AngularJS and convert the uploaded image into byte code, then send the byte code to the API service. How can we create bytecode using AngularJS?
Please guide me if you have any idea.

Thanks in advance
Raja

Answer (score 0):

It is not what you want, but maybe this plugin help you. This is just send all form data with files.

https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload